# How to block all notifications of other apps when my Android app is both running and not running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

I am building an Android application with the desire to block all notifications of other applications when my application is active or inactive. I have found that there is a way to block but only block when my application is active and inactive, it can't be blocked anymore. So, can someone help me find another way?

Comment: You need to get device admin access to do so with your app.

Comment: Would you mind explain a bit more ?

Comment: It' impossible. You cant block alll notification from other apps.

Comment: I have found some solutions that using NotificationListenerService to do so. Would it be possible ?